# How can i change typo3 admin URL?

Tags: typo3

I want to change admin url in typo3

currently admin URL is `http://www.example.com/typo3/`

I want to change it like below,

`http://www.example.com/dj28dgfad2jtsa47` (at least 12 digits!)
to hide the admin backend login.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As outline in the other answers, this is not possible. What you should do instead is to

1. Create a new subdomain that is allowed to access the `/typo3/` directory
2. Protect the `/typo3/` directory with the means of the webserver (e.g. `.htaccess`) to allow accessing the `/typo3/` path only if requested from the given subdomain

For example accessing `http://example.org/typo3/` would be forbidden, whereas `https://edit321.example.org/typo3/` would be allowed.

Comment: Like taht? SetEnvIf Host ^site\.com$ is_on_public_site
SetEnvIf Host ^www\.site\.com$ is_on_public_site
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from env=is_on_public_site

Answer (score 1):

renaming the directory will be very difficult to impossible.
A much simpler solution to protect the BE access would be to protect the path `/typo3/` by an htaccess password.
But keep in mind that there might be some access from the FE into the typo3 core with this path, e.g. if you use the core jQuery library, or some icons or images from the core (like flags) you need to copy these files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You could rename the `typo3/` directory, but this would break the code.

Comment: Yes, but i want to change admin url for typo3 BE security. So can't open BE third party.